# Get list of subcategories in subcategory with the same parent

Tags: php, wordpress, parent-child, categories

Maybe the title is a bit strange but I got this problem I cant figure out. I got this code that is getting a list of all the subcategories that are in the parent category.

My category structure is as follows:

- Parentcategory

  - Subcategory 1
  - Subcategory 2
  - Subcaterogy 3

When you are on the Parentcategory you get a list of all the subcategories. But when you are on the subcategory archive page the list is gone.

That makes perfect sense, but how can I make sure that when you are on the subcategory page, it keeps the list the same. That all categories are shown that have the same parent category as the current subcategory.

Is it possible to do this inside this code that I use one "archive-product.php"

```
<?php

    $term = get_queried_object();

    $children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
        'parent'    => $term->term_id,
        'hide_empty' => false
    ) );

    if ( $children ) { 
        foreach( $children as $subcat )
        {
            echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($subcat, $subcat->taxonomy)) . '">' . $subcat->name . '</a></li>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: check this answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/238229

Comment: You mean the part at: answered Sep 5 '16 at 8:08?

Comment: If you are on a category archive page for a sub-category, then `get_queried_object` should return that sub-category term object, if I am not mistaken. So you would have to find the parent category for that, and then use the parent term ID in `get_terms` - basically, what Max suggested. At least _properly_ explain how that is “not working” then. Do you get nothing at all, something else, does an error occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check your childs if they empty use:

```
$neighbors = get_terms( [
    'taxonomy'   => $term->taxonomy,
    'parent'     => $term->parent,
    'hide_empty' => false
] );
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but I tested this and it is not working for me. When I am on a subcategory I need a list of all the other subcategories and the current categorie of the same parent. I changed the code you provided to test it and no luck

Comment: I am very sorry Max, I was in a hurry and did not pay attention. I tried your solution and it worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: @user2812779 Good job

Comment: @user2812779 By the way after WP 4.5 recommend write 'taxonomy' in all arguments. Update example.

Comment: @user2812779 I think need check `0 !== $term->parent` yet.